# How to calculate the $\nabla \cdot \epsilon\nabla V = \nabla \epsilon \cdot \nabla V+\epsilon \nabla \cdot \nabla V $

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, inner-products

How to calculate the $\nabla \cdot \epsilon\nabla V = \nabla \epsilon \cdot \nabla V+\epsilon \nabla \cdot \nabla V $

I know the calculation of inner product and $\nabla$ ,but when if i have to calculate the in the same equation,i don't know how to calculate it,can anyone teach me or give me some hints?

Comment: What are $\epsilon$ and $V$? Are both scalars, or is $V$ a vector?

Comment: let us assume  both of them are vector,

Comment: In that case you have to be careful with the dimensions, as $\nabla V$ is the Jacobian with dimensions $N \times D$ where $N$ are the components of $V$ and $D$ are the spatial dimensions. In order that the expression you give makes sense, $\epsilon$ has to be of dimension $1\times N$, i.e., same number of entries as $V$.

In any case, the above equation is just the application of the product rule, which can be easily shown by writing the divergence operator as a sum of component-wise partial derivatives.

Comment: so is it corrected? $\nabla \cdot \epsilon\nabla V = \nabla \epsilon \cdot \nabla V+  (\nabla \cdot \nabla V)  \epsilon  $ ?